# Amazon S3 static website and Namecheap DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, namecheap

I am having trouble setting up DNS with Namecheap pointing to a static html website hosted in AWS S3.

Bucket config:
[image]

Currently, I get "chrisrich.io redirected you too many times."

[image]

This is the direct bucket url:
https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/chrisrich.io/index.html

AWS S3 bucket name:
[image]

DNS settings in Namecheap:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things:

1. The DNS record in Namecheap is for www.chrisrich.io and it's resolving to S3.
   dig www.chrisrich.io +short
   chrisrich.io.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com.
   s3-r-w.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com.
   52.95.134.34

To make it work with www.chrisrich.io, you need to have the bucket name exact same name as www.chrisrich.io. 
You can create a bucket with name www.chrisrich.io and put the files there , it should allow you to access your website using www.chrisrich.io.

2. You cannot have CNAME record for Apex domain chrisrich.io , it means you need to see if (URL forwarding) option available in Namecheap and chrisrich.io to www.chrisrich.io.

Also, Website endpoint doesn't support HTTPS, if you're planning to make your website work on https, you'll need cloudfront.

Answer (score 1):

Also, to make S3 website endpoint work using www.chrisrich.io, you need to change your DNS record, currently you're using the REST API name for the CNAME record, chrisrich.io.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com   --> this should be the name of S3 website endpoint otherwise, index page won't load automatically and you will need to access it using www.chrisrich.io/index.html

Comment: Just adding on: as of this writing, AWS website endpoints can be distinguished from AWS REST API endpoints by looking at their URLs: the website endpoints contain `s3-website` in their URLs, while the REST endpoints don't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your bucket name from **chrisrich.io** to **www.chrisrich.io**

Then, it will work.

Thanks